# RequireJS Optimizer is not combing files

Tags: requirejs

I am using the following build file and when I build (r.js -o jsbuild/build.js)  all the files in the 'script' folder are minified into the 'productionScripts' folder but they are not combined into the config.js file. Therefore I'm still getting the multiple http requests for all the dependencies.

Is there something wrong with my config or am I completely missing something about requireJS?

```
({
    appDir  : "../assets/scripts",
    baseUrl : "",
    dir     : "../assets/productionScripts",
    optimize: "uglify",
    paths: {
        config: 'assets/scripts/config'
    },
    modules: [
       {
           name: "config"
       }
    ],
    mainConfigFile : "../assets/scripts/config.js"
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course once I post I figure it out. I was mixing concepts. My config was saying minify the 'assets/scripts' folder and that's what it was doing.

I updated the script to just minify the main file. In this case 'assets/scripts/config.js' and that's when it combines dependencies. See appropriate config below. The key is to not use 'dir', 'appDir', and 'modules', this is specific to minifying the folder. Use 'out' to specify where dependencies will be minified and combined.

```
({
    baseUrl : "../assets/scripts",
    optimize: "uglify",
    name: 'config',
    mainConfigFile : "../assets/scripts/config.js",
    out: "../assets/productionScripts/config.js"
})
```