# Uglifying a RequireJS/Backbone project into one single .js file?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, minify, amd, uglifyjs

I worked along [the following tutorial](http://orizens.com/wp/topics/requirejs-optimizing-and-building-one-file/) to try to optimize my project into one single .js file, but unfortunately I can't seem to get the expected results. I get r.js to create an optimized folder for me, but instead of a single file, I get uglified copies of each individual .js file in their respective folders. Seems like that last concatenation step is somehow missing.

I'm trying to leverage an existing config file instead of using paths, I don't know if that specific step is breaking it.

My build/app.build.js is:

```
({
  appDir: '../',
  baseUrl: 'js',
  mainConfigFile: '../js/config.js',
  dir: '../../my-app-build',
  modules: [{
    name: 'main'
  }]
})
```

My main.js file has the config file as its dependency:

```
require(["config"], function() {
  require(['underscore', [...]
    [...]
  }
}
```

And the config file is where all of my project dependencies are declared:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  paths: {[...]},
  shim: {...]},
});
```

Does anyone have insight into why I might not be getting that single file output that I'm looking for? I tried the other approach [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256768/requirejs-optimizer-is-not-combing-files), but that only ever produces main.js for me with the config file prepended to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by the following option missing from the r.js build configuration file:

```
findNestedDependencies: true
```

Without it, r.js would not go past the first require in main.js, thus loading only config.js and none of the next level of dependencies. Just for reference (note that it saves the product of optimization in the same source folder, which is not ideal) looks like this:

```
({
  baseUrl: '.',
  mainConfigFile: 'config.js',
  name: 'main',
  out: 'main-build.js',
  findNestedDependencies: true,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got the solution from the Github Issue list. May be this configuration parameters will help you too

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/379

`If you only want one JS file built, instead of using dir: use out: for a single JS file build.`

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample build config file that worked for you? That'd be really helpful.

Comment: It is present in my projects repository on Github https://github.com/deeptechtons/BackboneGarage/blob/master/Widget/build.js

Comment: Is mainConfigFile interchangeable with paths, or do paths always have to be present? It would feel like duplication to me if I were to copy and paste what's already in my config file.

Comment: @AlexandrKurilin It is interchangeable with paths

Comment: appreciate the link, very helpful for my own reference! I found the answer tangentially.

Answer (score 0):

Specify output filepath:

```
({
    // ...
    out: '../main.min.js'
})
```